# Magento: 'Use categories path for product URL’s to no' - Will the old URLs be auto redirected?

Tags: url

I need to give specs on a magento site to set 'Use categories path for product URL’s to no', but will magento automatically redirect the old urls?

e.g:

I want to change the URLs, so URLs such as

```
www.example.com/blue-widgets/blue-widget1
www.example.com/new-blue-widgets/blue-widget1
```

will become:

```
www.example.com/blue-widget1
```

So what I want to know is will Magento automatically redirect the old URLs with the category in, to the new URLs without?  I don't have access to the site so cant test.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No.
Long(ish) answer: 
The old urls `category/subcategory/product.html` will still be available, you will see the same product page, but it will not redirect you to the product page with url `product.html`.
You will have to manually create redirect urls from the long url to the short one, but this is a painful and looooong process even for a few dozen products.

Comment: Right, I guess the next option will be setting 'Canonical Link Meta Tag For Products' to yes.

Comment: Yep...I think that's the easiest way.

Comment: In fact I think this is better for user experience any way. With URLs including the category URL the breadcrumbs will be correct so the user can go back to the previous category page. And that brings me to another questions, if 'Use categories path for product URL’s' is set to no, where will the breadcrumbs point to if a product is in multiple categories?

Comment: I think the breadcrumbs will look like this: 'Home'>>Product name. But just to make sure, try it.

Comment: Looks like Magento remembers what page you were on before and dynamicaly changes the breadcrumb navigation each time.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, go to System => Configuration => Catalog => Catalog => Search Engine Optimization and set "Use categories path for product URL’s" to “no”.

Comment: I already know how to do this, but i wanted to know if magento will auto redirect the old URL paths.